# Managing cross DB queries in microservices

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, microservices

i have `users` and `chats` microservices, with their separate databases, currently i decided to not use data duplication due to its high maintenance demands, and went for giving read access to `chats` microservice for `users` database, but now i have a problem, i need to fetch recent chats list which includes profile picture of user, name and text preview of last message. Problem is that i save only sender and receiver ids in message schema (mongodb) and i can not look it up in users database, because it would be very expensive to lookup each user separately, i know there is no correct way of doing it but i think this scenario can be quite common so how would you go for the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to give a look [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html) and read about 'Database per service' approach. In general, this is not a good practice to give microservice `x` direct access to the DB of microservice `y`. Each microservice should be aware of its own database only.
Instead of giving the `ChatService` access to users database, you can expose an API like `getUserById` in the `UserService`, and such that the `ChatService` (which holds the ID of a user) will request the user's details (name, picture, etc.) from the `UserService`. If you want to reduce calls from `ChatService` to `UserService`, you can consider caching of the users' data in the `ChatService` and then you don't have to do a call for each and every user.

Such that, you preserve the 'Database per service' pattern, you avoid making the users database a bottleneck, and you might even get better performance since with the right architecture API call should be faster than database call.

Comment: Still if i have exposed api getUserById and my list result number is say 10, it will be so expensive and time consuming that it won't be usable. and about caching users it is kind of the same idea as duplicating the data you need of user in users collection inside chat database, its not about memory but more about its maintenance, setting up event bus, writing crud for... so i don't think it will be a lot different if I did that with cache (redis) than database itself that i mentioned, I was looking for more optimal solution if it is even standardized

Comment: In software architecture there is no optimal/standardized solution, it is all about trade-off. You need to decide what characteristics are important for you (performance/scalability/deployability/testability/etc.), to pick the solution which fits the best those characteristics, and to take into consideration that other characteristics will be damaged.

Comment: I used the wrong word :), maybe it can be described better with just "third way", since performance is important, but also maintainability i want to know if some other way exists for it.

Answer (score 0):

An old topic - but maybe could be useful for someone. Try to ask yourself - do you really need to get all users and avatars? You can anonymize the names and use Latter-Avatars. Then if you really need to know who this user really is - you can make deanonymization when use clicks on the users avatar. Also you ofc could cache the users :)